# Pandas dataframe column forward fill from first non-zero value

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to forward fill specific dataframe columns from first non-zero value and I further want to do this for each group.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 5, 1], [1, 8, 0],[2, 4, 0],[2, 8, 1],[2, 81, 0]]),
                   columns=['ID', 'b', 'c'])
```

The result I want is:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 5, 1], [1, 8, 1],[2, 4, 0],[2, 8, 1],[2, 81, 1]]),
                   columns=['ID', 'b', 'c'])
```

Attempt:

```
df2 = df.groupby('ID',as_index = False)['c'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill'))
```

The problem is the original dataframe is not returned. Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try getting rid of `as_index=False` and `["c"]`, and instead using `df.groupby("ID").apply(...)`?

Comment: Thanks for that! The problem is that would also alter column "b"? I know in the reduced dataframe given, that would not occur, but I want to be able to specify the column to apply this over

Comment: I see, then assigning back to the columns you specified does the job i.e. `df[cols] = df.groupby(..)[cols].apply(...)`, as the answers below show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.values` attribute:

```
df['c']=df.groupby('ID',as_index = False)['c'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')).values
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your desired output:

```
    ID  b   c
0   1   0   0
1   1   5   1
2   1   8   1
3   2   4   0
4   2   8   1
5   2   81  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
df['c'] = df.groupby('ID')['c'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')) #print df after this.
```